# How to get editext values from recyclerview into a list of string

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

In my project `editext` fields(carname with price) in each item of `recyclerview`, when I `click` on save need to get all field values into a list of `string`, also when I entered values after scrolling values are interchanged. Here is my code.

```
private class PricesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PricesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

 @Override
 public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_cars_type_item, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(layoutView);
  }

 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.tvCarType.setText(carsList.get(position));
    holder.edtPrice.setText("");
    holder.edtPrice.setTag(position);
  }

@Override
   public int getItemCount() {
   return carsList.size();
  }

@Override
   public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   return super.getItemViewType(position);
  }

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

  TextView tvCarType;
  EditText edtPrice;

  public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
     super(itemView);
     tvCarType=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCarType);
     edtPrice=(EditText)itemView.findViewById(R.id.edtPrice);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the method to get list of string from editext values.

```
public List<string> getPriceValues(){
   List<String> priceList = new ArrayList<>();

   for (int i = 0; i < carsList.size(); i++) {

     View viewHolder=rvPrices.getRootView();

     View view1=mLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(i);
     View view=rvPrices.getChildAt(i);
     View root=rvPrices.getRootView();
     //            PricesAdapter.MyViewHolder myViewHolder=(PricesAdapter.MyViewHolder)rvPrices.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(i);
             //            String price=myViewHolder.edtPrice.getText().toString().trim();
     EditText edtPrice=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edtPrice);
     String price = edtPrice.getText().toString().trim();
     priceList.add(price);
  }                    
  return priceList;
}
```

Here is the error i have.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: `also when i entered values after scrolling values are interchanged. `. You should first solve that 'feature' . It makes no sense to tackle other problems first.

Comment: A `RecyclerView` actually removes `Views` when they are not visible anymore, so, it's not possible to retrieve edittext values from invisible rows. Unless you cache these values in your  Application.

Comment: `view.findViewById(R.id.edtPrice);`. You discovered that your NullPointerException comes from this statement? Well it does. So view==null. Check before use. You cannot get the text from edittexts belonging to views which are not visible any more.

Comment: @greenapps How not to values interchanged after scrolling, is there any solution? or i have to add EditText programmatically, give me exact answer.

Comment: Exact answer? You are not a!one! You are number 12345 with this problem. Read about recycling as the views get recycled. If you google you find solutions as 12343 people solved this problem already.

Answer (score 0):

Your current implementation will not work as you expect it. If you enter text into any EditText and you start to scroll enough the system will recycle the Views that were scrolled offscreen and you'll start to see repeated text start to appear that was previously scrolled of the screen.
Fix: you should create an ArrayList or Array of Strings. Inside of MyViewHolder you should implement a text change listener and whenever the text of the EditText changes you add that text value into the ArrayList for the logical position of the given ViewHolder using the method getAdapterPosition(). The method getAdapterPositio is a method on the ViewHolder class that all subclasses default inherit. Use the value of that method as the index into your ArrayList/array and then store the text value you retrieve from the text change listener. Inside of the onBindViewHolder() method of your adapter, you should check the ArrayList/array with the position argument to check if a string is present, if one is set it on the EditText otherwise if null manually set the text to an empty string. This will make sure you don't see your text values incorrectly being recycled during scrolling.

Comment: If there are five views visible then the position of which view would be delivered by getAdapterPosition()? The one that that is edited at that moment? Cannot imagine that.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what will happen. But you must assign the Text change listener on every MyViewHolder's EditText.

Comment: I do not believe that. Assuming that getAdapterPosition() has no parameters.

Comment: @greenapps Your beliefs don't affect reality. Check it out? I've implemented this logic before and it works.

Comment: I hope OP checks it out ;-).

Comment: The method getAdapterPosition doesn't need to take any parameters. The method will internally ask the RecyclerView the position of itself. View the source code inside RecyclerView. This is exact same pattern you'd use to implement click functionality.